# Spring Cloud Gateway to modify HREF static HTML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, api-gateway

I have a Spring Gateway and a Webflux service behind it. The route is;

```
server:
  port: 9999
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route1
        predicates:
          - Path=/1/**
        uri: http://localhost:8081
        filters:
          - RewritePath=/1/(?<myPath>.*), /$\{myPath}
```

If I request `localhost:9999/1/index.html`, it translates to `localhost:8081/index.html` and the page is correctly returned.

However, in the HTML I have links and references, for example

```
<a href="/microService1">test1</a>
```

How would I get the Gateway to return the HTML with corrected HREF? (i.e. return the HTML as);

```
<a href="/1/microService1">test1</a>
```

On a side note; is it common or accepted practice to host static HTML, CSS and JS in the Webflux/Netty server containing the microservices, or should they be placed somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the first / in your href

```
<a href="microService1">test1</a>
```

Or add a .

```
<a href="./microService1">test1</a>
```

Comment: I went down the rabbit hole of Spring Gateway, RouteLocators and modifyResponseBody. I never considered using relative as opposed to absolute addresses! The solution works. Thanks Khaled!